# Can #2 wire be used for a 100’ away sub panel

Tags: wiring, gauge, electrical-panel

I want to add a sub panel 100’ from my main 110 panel to power my new addition to my house. Question can I use a #2 wire on a 80amp breaker to my sub panel and have the wire in place for upgrade later to a 220 service and sub panel to a 100 amp will I run in to problem in the year between projects?

Answer (score 2):

2 AWG *copper* with 75C rating will get you over 100A. However, 2 AWG *aluminum* is a **lot** cheaper and will only get you to 90A when used this way. (As I understand it, there are main service feed calculations which allow higher service on 2 AWG aluminum, but not on a subpanel feed.) So the question then is whether you will really need 100A or whether 90A is enough. Which depends on:

- Size of building
- HVAC requirements
- Large built-in appliances
- Type of water heating (gas is no or minimal electric, tanked water low electric, on demand electric can use 100A all by itself)

and a bunch of other factors.